# Texture Paint - Why is my object plain white and not paintable?

Tags: texture-painting

[image: Texture paint]

I want to Texture Paint something and my texture is white. In material viewport and render preview it appears completely white, without shades. I also can´t paint on it, if i try nothing happens. What can I do? Here´s the file (hope it works):

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vzwcsr3ridb8ahg/AABo0ZRR8cQG5T-_2JdNQMfya?dl=0

[image: screenshot]

I changed the texture to black with 1024px and added the Diffuse Node and toyed along with the viewports. Still can´t  paint on the object.

Comment: plug it into a DIffuse node before the Output. Why can't you paint on it? Maybe share your file

Comment: The Diffuse Shader just makes the object pink. I uploaded the file and linked it above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any HDRI picture for your world (or at least you haven't packed it) so the background is pink, remove the *Environment Texture* node from the *World Shader Editor*:

[image]

Back to *Shader Editor > Object* mode, plug the *Image Texture* into a *Diffuse* node, maybe load a lighter picture (the current one is 6144 px large)?

[image]

Create a sun in the scene, give it a *Strength* of 4 (just to check the result in *Rendered* preview mode). Select your anvil and switch it to *Texture Paint*, try to paint, if it still doesn't work, switch from a mode to another (From *Material Preview* to *Solid*) and then back to the mode you want (except *Render* preview). It should work.

For your last question:

- Choose *Blend > Mix* instead of *Add*
- Close the *Texture Mask*
- Keep the *Texture* if you want but in that case choose another color than black.

[image]

Comment: I opened the file again today. I have shades now, but still can´t paint on the object. I actually use a  HDRI picture, but didn´t pack it. Sry.

Comment: have you tried to switch from a display mode to another? Maybe share your file again?

Comment: i have added the current file under the old link. switching between display modes didn´t change anything.

Comment: @Irenäus Blaszkiewicz I've edited my answer, I hope it will fix your problem

Comment: It worked somehow, but I am not sure if it has something to do with the lighting, I just pushed my point lightsource further away.

Comment: mmh what do you mean, I didn't talk about lighting

Comment: you recommended making a sun.

Comment: oh ok, it's not important, it's just to check the result in Rendered preview mode  ;)